# convert `[object Object]` and append it in a class.?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery

**Q1.** How can convert `[object Object]` to word?
**LIKE:** `[object Object]` =to=> `salam`

**Q2.** How can append outputs result search[after click on it] in class `.list` with(mid) tow input.
**LIKE**: If resulet search was value `salam` and after click on it get as:

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HZMP3/6/):

```
[object Object] -> input ... & input ...    
[object Object] -> input ... & input ...
[object Object] -> input ... & input ...
```

Js:

```
$('.auto_complete').keyup(function () {
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        //url: 'http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/auto_complete',
        url: 'auto_complete',
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var id_name = $('.list_autobox_hotel').attr('id');
            $('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
            if (data == 0) {
                $('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('<p><b>there is no</b></p>');
            } else {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('<p id="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</p>').appendTo('.list_autobox_hotel');
                });
                //////////////////////*HERE Q1//////////////////////
                $('.list_autobox_hotel p').bind("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var ac = $(this).attr('id');
                    var ok = $.grep(data, function (e) {
                        return e.name == ac;
                    })[0].units;
                    //alert(ok);
                    /////////////*HERE Q2//// for append////////
                    $(ok).appendTo('.list');

                    /////////////HERE Q2*////////////
                    $(this).remove();
                    return false;
                });

                //////////////////////HERE Q1*//////////////////////
                $('body').click(function () {
                    $(".list_autobox_hotel p").hide().remove();
                    $('.auto_complete').val('');
                    $('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
                    $('.list_autobox_hotel').css('display', 'none');
                });

            }
        },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP[insert to database]:

```
  $units = array();
  $name_units = $this->input->post('name_units');
  $price_units = $this->input->post('price_units');
  $checkbox_units = $this->input->post('checkbox_units');
  foreach ($name_units as $idx=>$name){
      $units[] = array(
    'name_units' => $name_units[$idx],
    'price_units' => $price_units[$idx],
    'checkbox_units' => $checkbox_units[$idx],
      );
  }
 $data = array('name' =>$this -> input -> post('name'),              
               'units' => json_encode($units)
 );

      $this -> db -> insert('hotel_submits', $data);
```

PHP[select code]:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($query_hotel_search->result() as $row)
{
   $units = json_decode($row->units);
   $data[] = array('name' => $row->name, 'units' =>$units );
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

**DEMO:** There are here the contents of the database and output code PHP and test code for you => [CLICK HERE](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

**UPDATE:** `json` response:

Output values `salam` & `salavat` of php code: [this values select(`selcet * from ...`) by `json_encode()`]

salam:

> [{"name":"salam","units":[{"name_units":"salam","price_units":"74,554","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman"]},{"name_units":"mokhles","price_units":"4,851,269","checkbox_units":["mobleman","tv"]},{"name_units":"fadat","price_units":"85,642","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman","tv"]}]}]

salavat:

> [{"name":"salavat","units":[{"name_units":"salam","price_units":"5,452","checkbox_units":null},{"name_units":"khobe","price_units":"5,452,545","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman"]}]}]

Comment: very very difficult to understand, can you post your json response?

Comment: I do not understand this question, but re 1), are you loooking for [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)?

Comment: Please see update post. here was content database and `json` response: http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign )

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### my answer is totally based on assumption you are getting this json as response when i searched **"salam"**

```
[
    {
        "name": "salam",
        "units": [
            {
                "name_units": "salam",
                "price_units": "74,554",
                "checkbox_units": [
                    "minibar",
                    "mobleman"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name_units": "mokhles",
                "price_units": "4,851,269",
                "checkbox_units": [
                    "mobleman",
                    "tv"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name_units": "fadat",
                "price_units": "85,642",
                "checkbox_units": [
                    "minibar",
                    "mobleman",
                    "tv"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

in the `success` callback iterate over the json as follow

```
if (data == 0) {
$('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('<p><b>there is no</b></p>');
 }
 else
 {
  $.each(data[0].units, function (index, value) {
   $('<p id="' + data[0].units[index].name_units + '">' + data[0].units[index].name_units + '</p>').appendTo('.list_autobox_hotel');
  });
```

### **here is a demo hopefully you will get the idea http://jsfiddle.net/BBSyy/**

**EDIT**

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BBSyy/1/

### **Another Edit**

see this fiddle with `grep` example  http://jsfiddle.net/BBSyy/3/

Comment: That's right but my mean was about this part: `$('.list_autobox_hotel p').bind("click", function (e) {...`. after click append value(`data[0].units[index].name_units`) with tow input. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HZMP3/7/ how is it for this part?

Comment: yes i get json response but with use your code in `$('.list_autobox_hotel p').bind("click", function (e) {...});` it not work true for me. Please you help me in `$.grep(data, function (e) {
                        return e.name == ac;
                    })[0].units;
` that in it is result search `object`?

Comment: you good understand my mean but still output `$('.list_autobox_hotel p').bind("click", function (e) {...});`=>`$.grep(data, function (e) {
                        return e.name == ac;
                    })[0].units;
` is `[object Object]`. !?

Comment: that is because you are returning  an object have a look on another edit

Comment: also a piece of advice don't use alert for debugging use `console.log(ok)` and see what does your object look like

Comment: It does not work in my code, after a click on `$('.list_autobox_hotel p')` nothing event no. !? see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/g3TMA/

Comment: What is your opinion about the PHP code? (did they are best? what is the best way for php?)